# how to loop this slider function?

Tags: jquery

I need to somehow make this image slider loop after completion, but I'm not sure how I can accomplish this. I know this question has been answered before, but I've tried Googling it, tried different solutions etc. but I can't get it working on this slider I made from a tutorial. All help is appreciated, thanks!

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('.img-slider img.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) {
        $active = $('#slideshow img:last');
    }

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? 
        $active.next() : $('#slideshow img:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('active').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, 
        function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active')
        }
    );
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
    slideSwitch();
});
```

Comment: I fixed your indentation for you

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JGL2N/1/

Comment: @user2532000 let me know if that works... I'll post it as an answer then

Comment: @ArunPJohny Tried that one just now, copied it over directly to test it, it stops at the last image like with the code I had before :/

Comment: @user2532000 the fiddle seems to be working isn't it... can you try to recreate the case using a fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JGL2N/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny For some reason the slider isn't working on the fiddle, which I don't understand, but either way, here's the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/9xzfU/

Comment: @user2532000 element with id `slideshow` is missing

Comment: @user2532000 see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kswd6/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny thank you so much for having patience with me, that was a silly mistake of mine! I really appreciate your time and help, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(slideSwitch(), 5000 );
  slideSwitch();
});
```

Remove the quotation marks from your slideSwitch() function in the setInterval() function.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
    slideSwitch();
});
```

To:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval( slideSwitch, 5000 );
    slideSwitch();
});
```

`setInterval` takes a function and a number as parameters, and you were feeding it a string, and a number.

Comment: Can't get this working either, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I copied it over directly. :/

Comment: @user2532000 What exactly isn't working? What isn't happening? We need more information or a JSFiddle that replicates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check and replace your code with this lines :

```
$(function() {
    setInterval( slideSwitch(), 5000 );
    slideSwitch();
});
```

Comment: Can't get that one working for some reason, thanks for the suggestion though.